# jQuery multiple values update issue

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code which does not work as I expect it. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I dont see it. Basically if a blog is not publish, when I click on the image, it accesses my DB and updates it accordingly. All of that is fine.

1. I click on .not_published
2. The content of .not_published is changed with an image tag that display ajax-loader.gif
3. When the server returns a success message, I update the html of #not_published parent with a new content which includes replacing .not_published with .published.

[image: Blog Post List]

All I get when I click on the .not_published is the ajax image loading and it stays there. If I add an `alert("message');` inside the success function it works fine.

[image: Loading Image]

List point 3 does not work. I cant figure out why. Please see code below:

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on('click','.not_published', function(){
       var ID = $(this).siblings("p").text();
        $(this).html("<img style=\"padding-left:15px;\" src=\"/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif\">");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/posts/publish/"+ID,
            type: "post",
            data: '',
            success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){
                $(this).parent().html("<span class=\"published\"><img style=\"width:20px;\" src=\"/img/admin/checkmark_green.png\"></span><p style=\"display: none\">ID</p>");
            },
            error: function(responseText){
                alert(responseText);
            }   
        });
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="publish">
    <span id="not_published">
        <img style="width:20px"  src="/img/admin/checkmark_red.png">
    </span>"
    <p style="display: none">1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you loading the image via ajax and not have it load directly and just change the source? also why should you change the id, when you could change classes with the same effect. the id "must" be unique to work properly. try HADI's Solution

Comment: IDs MUST be unique. Use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store  the element in variable outside of the AJAX request but before you do... inside success handler log `this` to console. It's not what you think it is.

ALso changing ID to class as noted in comments

```
$(document).on('click','.not_published', function(){
       var ID = $(this).siblings("p").text();
        var $el=$(this).html("<img style=\"padding-left:15px;\" src=\"/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif\">");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/posts/publish/"+ID,
            type: "post",
            data: '',
            success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){
                 /* change $(this) to $el defined above*/
                $el.parent().html("<span class=\"published\"><img style=\"width:20px;\" src=\"/img/admin/checkmark_green.png\"></span><p style=\"display: none\">ID</p>");
            },
            error: function(responseText){
                alert(responseText);
            }   
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I created `var publish = $(this)` before the `$.ajax` call and used `publish.parent().html(` inside the `success: function(` and it works great.

Comment: good lesson about `this` in ajax request..been there done that!

Answer (score 3):

You are using id #publish and #not_published. try using class instead of using multiple #not_published like .not_published

and check var ID before sending

Comment: I have changed everything to class and still the same issues... I have updated my question with the changes as you suggested

Comment: value of ID is correct. I have done alert(ID) and it is correct.

Comment: can you use live function?

Comment: Hi.. `charlietfl` suggestion works with a little modification. Thanks for the help